# Need text with icon in Vue js loader

Tags: javascript, vue.js, loader

This is code

```
<loading :active.sync="isLoading" :can-cancel="true"></loading>
```

please help me to add text inside the Vue loader below the loading icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<loading :active.sync="isLoading" :can-cancel="true">
<div class="loading-icon"></div>
Some text below the icon
</loading>
```